# Memory not getting freed up in Asp.Net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, memory, asp.net-core, garbage-collection

I have an issue where the memory is not getting freed up in my .NET Core Web API. All I am doing is simply returning a string from a static class.

API:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    return A.get();
}

public static class A
{
    public static string get()
    {
        return "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    }
}
```

Client:

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    //var v = hc.GetAsync("http://localhost:52425/api/values").result;
    hc.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:52425/api/values");
    if(i%1000 == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Sleeping-----------" + i);
    }
}
```

I have tried returning the string directly from the action method without the static class. I have also tried to call the API from the client in synchronous fashion rather than async. None of these made any difference.

This screenshot shows that where GC is called once but does not help clear up the memory.

[image: memory from diagnostics]

Here are the diagnostics after upgrading to 2.0 and disabling telemetry info:

[image]

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: Also, are you running WebAPI on IIS or Kestrel?

Comment: i am using netcore1.2 and i am running on IIS. the above code when run on cloudfoundry with 256 ram throwing OOM exception

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Application Insights is collecting data even when you are not using it and thus you see memory increase. After some time those objects are collected by GC.

Application insights are turned on by default by Visual Studio. There are two options to turn off Application Insights:

1. Add `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;` to ConfigureServices and you should see performance improvements.
2. In launchSettings.json add `ASPNETCORE_preventHostingStartup` key:

> ```
> "environmentVariables": {
>     "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
>     "ASPNETCORE_preventHostingStartup": "True"
>   }
> ```

This one could potentionaly tun off some other stuff. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2051).

Comment: after 100k request i am hitting the service ocassionally. i continued running the app for few hours and the memory did not come down. i will try the option you mentioned and update the results back here. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Also, I would suggest switching to .NET Core 2.0 since there are a lot of improvements.

Comment: upgrading to 2.0 and turning off telemetry helped in performance(processor) but did not really help memory. there was not even once the GC is called(screen shot added to actual question). I am guesing GC is looking at available ram(12GB free on my PC) before taking action. any idea how i can control this. one more thing i observed when in cloudfoundry(2 1Gb instances) with netcore1.2 is if the memory reaches around ~900Mb then gc clears up the memory and stays around ~350MB. But if the same cloud foundry instance are 512 each GC never works fine and i get OOM error.

Comment: I think that you should file a ticket on [asp.net core github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues). Also, leave a link to the ticket here just in case that someone comes here searching for the solution for the same issue.