# .NET Core Website consumes a lot of memory

Tags: asp.net, performance, memory, .net-core, hosting

I have a website that is built on top of ASP.NET .NET Core 2.0 and it worked for 8 months without any issues but 2 days ago i got a message from the host provider that my website is consuming 33GB of RAM which made them suspend my account so i asked them to limit my resources according to my Plan which is only 2GB physical and 4GB Virtual, and that made my website pool stops about 6 or more times per day and i have to restart it manually to get the website back,
i have tested they website using Resharper DotMemory Tool and the Visual Studio 
Diagnostic Tools (which i'm new for such operation), and i see that the website start with about 300MB of RAM and it keeps raising while using the website, but its top is 1.1GB RAM as here (
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4inRq.png))

so i'm not sure what should be the solution as the host provider tells me to upgrade to VPS or optimize my website(that i haven't made any Coding changes for about 3 months (Only Data Entry))

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I recommend to check official GitHub repository and open an issue there:
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=memory

Also you may find some very recent similar issues.

Also check out Application telemetry, tho it probably won't help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671597/memory-not-getting-freed-up-in-asp-net-core-api

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll find any answers here with the information provided.  Do you have any suspicions where the issue may lie, what is the datastore, what libraries are you using?  Are you running the latest versions from nuget?

Comment: Thanks guys for helping, after a lot of investigation i found that what causes the problem was the Blog part, i have eager loaded posts with tags and that increased the RAM consuming from 700MB to 5.5GB in just a click, i have commented that code, and currently my top RAM usage is 850MB, Thanks for your help and passing by